# Jung coloring vertex with value

Tags: java, jung, vertex, edges

I'm stuck at the moment with the Java library Jung.

I display vertices and edges, only I can not find any functions for vertex coloring that I need with the value of the vertices and not with the mouse.

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.PickableVertexPaintTransformer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.DefaultVertexLabelRenderer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.Renderer.VertexLabel.Position;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.ConstantTransformer;

public class Design {
     public Graph<String, Integer> g;
    public Design() {     

         this.g = ProjectTools.readNet("SmallTown.net");
    }

    public static <Paint> void main(String[] args) {
        Design sgv = new Design(); 
        Layout<Integer, String> layout = new FRLayout(sgv.g);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(800,800));  
        BasicVisualizationServer<Integer, String> vv =
            new BasicVisualizationServer<Integer, String>(layout);

        Transformer<Integer,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer,Paint>() {
            public Paint transform(Integer i) {
                return (Paint) Color.GREEN;
            }
        };  

        vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850,850));
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelRenderer(new DefaultVertexLabelRenderer(Color.green));
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(Color.white));
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(new BasicStroke(2.5f)));

        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer((Transformer<Integer, java.awt.Paint>) vertexPaint);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(new PickableVertexPaintTransformer<Integer>(vv.getPickedVertexState(), Color.green, Color.yellow));

        vv.setBackground(Color.gray);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Integer>());
        vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Projet Algo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(vv); 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

My rendering :
[image: Vertices and edges]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see two possible problems; you are calling `setVertexFillPaintTransformer` twice and `BasicVisualizationServer` dosn't seem to like `DefaultModalGraphMouse`.

Try this version:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Paint;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.functors.ConstantTransformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.DefaultModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.picking.PickedInfo;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.DefaultVertexLabelRenderer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.Renderer.VertexLabel.Position;

public class Design {
     public Graph<Integer, String> g;
    public Design() {     

         this.g = ProjectTools.readNet("SmallTown.net");
    }

    private static class VertexPaintTransformer implements Transformer<Integer,Paint> {

        private final PickedInfo<Integer> pi;

        VertexPaintTransformer ( PickedInfo<Integer> pi ) { 
            super();
            if (pi == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("PickedInfo instance must be non-null");
            this.pi = pi;
        }

        @Override
        public Paint transform(Integer i) {
            Color p = null;
            //Edit here to set the colours as reqired by your solution
            if ( i % 2 == 0)
                p = Color.GREEN;
            else
                p =  Color.RED;
            //Remove if a selected colour is not required
            if ( pi.isPicked(i)){
                p = Color.yellow;
            }
            return p;
        }
    }

    public static <Paint> void main(String[] args) {
        Design sgv = new Design(); 
        Layout<Integer, String> layout = new FRLayout(sgv.g);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(800,800));  
        VisualizationViewer<Integer, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<Integer, String>(layout);

        Transformer<Integer,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer,Paint>() {

            @Override
            public Paint transform(Integer i) {
                if ( i % 2 == 0)
                    return (Paint) Color.GREEN;
                else
                    return  (Paint) Color.RED;
            }
        };  

        vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850,850));
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelRenderer(new DefaultVertexLabelRenderer(Color.green));
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(Color.white));
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(new BasicStroke(2.5f)));

        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(new VertexPaintTransformer(vv.getPickedVertexState()));

        DefaultModalGraphMouse graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
        graphMouse.setMode(edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);
        vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);

        vv.setBackground(Color.gray);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Integer>());
        vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Projet Algo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(vv); 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

I've repalced your `Transformer` with a new version `VertexPaintTransformer` that supports selection, removed the second use of `setVertexFillPaintTransformer` and swithced you from a `BasicVisualizationServer` to `VisualizationViewer` so I can use a picking `GraphMouse`

[image]

I had to mock your `ProjectTools#readNet()` method but Ihope you can see the Odd, Even and Selected colours.

You can now modify `VertexPaintTransformer#transform()` as required

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your code does not work for my configuration. I don't want to use my mouse to color the points. I want to add points to color directly in my code.

Comment: @Daleksek "I don't want to use my mouse to color the points"  but you where using a `PickableVertexPaintTransformer` implying you wanted to pick vertices.  Nevertheless you can still change the implementation of `VertexPaintTransformer#transform()` to your requirements without using the mouse.  Why doe you try the code and see what it does, you should get alternating green and red vertices.